# SyntaxError when loading local TileJSON with Wax and Leaflet

Tags: json, maps, mapbox, tilemill

I have this TileJSON file:

```
{
    "tilejson": "1.0.0",
    "bounds": [ -6.6028, 49.689, 1.9446, 55.943 ],
    "center": [ -1.7029, 52.703, 6 ],
    "minzoom": 6,
    "maxzoom": 15,
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "tiles": [
        "http://localhost:8081/data/oa_belonging_tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
    ]
}
```

and I'm creating a map with this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    wax.tilejson('data/oa_belonging_tiles/metadata.json',
            function(tilejson) {
                var map = new L.Map('map-div')
                        .addLayer(new wax.leaf.connector(tilejson))
                        .setView(new L.LatLng(51, 0), 1);
                wax.leaf.legend(map, tilejson).appendTo(map._container);
            });
</script>
```

When I execute the script in the browser, I get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : metadata.json:2
```

I have followed the TileJSON specification, and I see no typos/other problem in the file. I cleared the browser cache and I'm 100% sure I'm loading the correct file. I've experimented with removing some of the keys/values but the problem persists.

I would appreciate any advice on how to load tiles locally.

Answer (score 1):

I have made it to work by storing tilejson in a variable. It now loads the tiles without any problems:

```
var tilejson = {
        bounds: [-6.6028, 49.689, 1.9446, 55.943 ],
        center: [-1.7029, 52.703, 6],
        maxzoom: 15,
        minzoom: 6,
        scheme: "xyz",
        tilejson: "2.0.0",
        tiles: ["http://localhost:8081/data/oa_belonging_tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"],
        version: "1.0.0"
    };

var map = new L.Map('map')
        .addLayer(new wax.leaf.connector(tilejson))
        .setView(new L.LatLng(53, -1.7), 6);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your not opposed to using https://www.mapbox.com/, you could provide much more tile options. I had a similar problem, see below for a snippet of how you could replace the whole tilejson object. Here is how mapbox works https://www.mapbox.com/guides/how-mapbox-works/.

Edit: Of course while still using leaflet, as I did. Also used the updated version of wax connector. http://www.geosprocket.com/mapbox-wax/manual/index.html#downloads

//HTML

```
     <div id="map"></div>
```

JS Script

```
     L.mapbox.accessToken = 'token';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map','yourmapid')
    .setView([yourlocation], 15);
```